# how to save an image with text on another image?

Tags: iphone, image, textview, cgimage

I any one have idea about taking snapshot from iphone application through coding.

means.

I am developing an iphone application where there will be two images dynamically comes. There will be a text view with clear color on those particular images. users will be able to write any text on the images and click save button. Then those particular images will have to be saved in database along with text or have to save them in iphone library along with text.

we may need to convert the image along with text as an another image.. ? or do any one have any ideas about this kind of challenging task..

Please help.

Thanks in advance to you all....